# Makefile to compile Fortran source files in different directories

Tags: makefile, fortran, dependency-management, directory

Here is my problem: I have been using Java for many years and enjoy having many directories separating different areas of the code. For my current project I am writing Fortran code, which should compile under Windows and Unix/Linux. For Windows, I am using Eclipse/Photran with MinGW/gfortran tools to set up Makefiles.

Here is the desired project structure (deep nesting tree-like Java-like would be even nicer)

```
dir1/src/*.f95
dir1/make/Makefile_lib1.any
dir1/make/Makefile_lib1.win
dir1/make/Makefile_lib1.unix

dir2/src/*.f
dir2/make/Makefile_lib2.any
dir2/make/Makefile_lib2.win
dir2/make/Makefile_lib2.unix

...

dir_main/src/*.f or *.f95
dir_main/make/Makefile_main.any
dir_main/make/Makefile_main.win
dir_main/make/Makefile_main.unix
```

I would like to call `make Makefile_main.unix`, which would set up any Unix-specific variables and then include `Makefile_main.any`, `Makefile_lib1.any`, ...

(similar for making on Windows)

I got to the stage where I can see all source files in a given directory, e.g.

```
SRCS  := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.$(SRC_EXT))
```

Now I am struggling with how to make all dependencies as in Fortran 95 each source generates `*.o` and `*.mod`.

Is there a way to switch between directories when compiling so that all targets/dependencies do not have dir-path in their names? Note that I am calling `make` from some other service directory where the Eclipse project lives. Any suggestions how to proceed?

I really do not want to do the usual Fortran style of having just one directory with 
all the mess together with the code.

Comment: If you have `dir2/src/foo.f`, where do you want `foo.o` and `foo.mod` to go? And are there any dependencies between "area" directories?

Comment: there are many better ways to do what I think you want to do, many of them outlined in some of the related questions, and there are probably dozens of guides available just a short Google away.  The fact you're using fortran is irrelevant.  One word that might help in your search is "recursive", as in "recursive makefiles".

Answer (score 0):

There are two major strategies you can take.

You can place a makefile in each subdirectory and have it support targets like `all`, `clean` etc, then use recursive make invocations from the top-level makefile to make the same target (e.g. `all`) in every subdirectory.

Alternatively, you can handle it all in one make invocation, without recursing, but then you'll have to work with relative paths containing subdirectory names. Personally I don't see a problem with it, and I've maintained a system of makefiles based on this approach.

Here is what you can do in your case, assuming that `SRC` is set correctly to the list of relative paths to every source you need to compile.

```
# This replaces the SRC_EXT suffix with .o in each filename
OBJ = $(SRC:%.$(SRC_EXT)=%.o)

$(BINARY_NAME): $(OBJ)
    ...link command...

%.o: %.$(SRC_EXT)
    ...compile command...
```